# MySQL query to order two column, one ASC another DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to prepare a subject wise merit list. I am using this `mysql query`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM results 
ORDER BY qid ASC,
    marks DESC
```

Result is:

[image]

But what I need is like this (look at marks column, I need to get same `qid` rows, ordered by `marks`):

[image]

Please anyone help me.

**Update:**
And this is `result.sql` file to create the table in your pc.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 09, 2013 at 05:40 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.27
-- PHP Version: 5.4.7

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `ges_omeca`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `results`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `results` (
  `exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `corrects` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `total_qs` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `marks` float NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'DateTime when user submits the answer script.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`exam_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `results`
--

INSERT INTO `results` (`exam_id`, `sid`, `qid`, `corrects`, `total_qs`, `marks`, `date_time`) VALUES
(1, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-B)_(07.02.13)', 37, 40, 36.25, '2023-02-13 01:10:00'),
(2, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-B)_(07.02.13)', 11, 40, 10.25, '2013-02-23 01:56:58'),
(3, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-D)_(10.02.13)', 2, 100, 36.25, '2013-02-23 03:42:57'),
(4, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-B)_(09.02.13)', 5, 40, 5, '2013-02-23 03:46:59'),
(5, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-A)_(07.02.13)', 1, 40, 0.25, '2013-02-23 04:46:59'),
(6, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-A)_(07.02.13)', 6, 40, 5.5, '2013-02-23 04:59:59'),
(7, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-D)_(10.02.13)', 10, 100, 9.25, '2013-02-24 08:57:17'),
(8, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-B)_(09.02.13)', 5, 40, 5, '2013-02-24 01:23:50'),
(9, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-D)_(07.02.13)', 0, 40, -0.5, '2013-02-25 12:45:33'),
(10, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-D)_(07.02.13)', 2, 40, 1.5, '2013-02-25 01:45:38'),
(11, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-B)_(09.02.13)', 2, 40, 2, '2013-02-25 04:06:28'),
(12, 'guest', 'EN_(Set-C)_(07.02.13)', 5, 40, 4.5, '2013-02-25 04:42:27'),
(13, 'guest', 'P1_(Set-C)_(10.02.13)', 6, 40, 6, '2013-02-25 05:00:57');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: The date `2023-02-13` seems legit to me. How are you generating the desired result?

Comment: that was edited by me :D, please do not think anything else without just `qid` and `marks` :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is exactly what you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
ORDER BY SUBSTRING( qid
FROM 1 
FOR 1 ) ASC , marks DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really understand your question but looking on the result, I've noticed that records are sorted by `qid` which contains `EN` to be the first on the result list.

give this a try,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
ORDER   BY  CASE WHEN qid LIKE 'EN%' THEN 0 
                WHEN qid LIKE 'P1%' THEN 1
                ELSE 2
            END ASC,
            marks DESC
```

Comment: but the table may contain manything without just EN & P1. Thats why I like to ORDER them.

Comment: @CoolBrain this is custom ordering. you need to manually get the list of it or if you don't to do that, add a column on your table which groups your records and can be sorted through that column.

Comment: @JW.- ok I will add a column as you suggested, but what kind of column? update in SQLFiddle please...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM results
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(qid FROM 1 FOR 9) ASC,
         marks DESC
```