# ORDER BY with multiple column in different directions (ASC & DESC)

Tags: logparser

Not sure if my issue is with Log Parser itself, or with [Log Parser Studio](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765)...

Trying to run something like this in LPS interface:

```
SELECT cs-uri-query, TO_LOCALTIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time)) AS fullTime
FROM  '[LOGFILEPATH]'
ORDER BY cs-uri-query ASC, fullTime DESC
```

but I get:

```
Error parsing query: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: ','
[SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
```

If I remove `ASC`, query goes thru, but column `cs-uri-query` is also sorted in descending order:

```
src=web  08/08/18 05:55:29
src=web  07/08/18 10:44:43
src=web  07/08/18 03:55:16

src=rss  08/08/18 03:40:59
src=rss  08/08/18 03:40:17
src=rss  07/08/18 04:30:37

src=eml  09/08/18 09:49:51
src=eml  09/08/18 08:13:01
src=eml  09/08/18 07:55:58
```

Is there a way to use `ORDER BY` with two columns sorted in different directions?

```
src=eml  09/08/18 09:49:51
src=eml  09/08/18 08:13:01
src=eml  09/08/18 07:55:58

src=rss  08/08/18 03:40:59
src=rss  08/08/18 03:40:17
src=rss  07/08/18 04:30:37

src=web  08/08/18 05:55:29
src=web  07/08/18 10:44:43
src=web  07/08/18 03:55:16
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313043/mysql-query-to-order-two-column-one-asc-another-desc

Comment: @Justin-Le No, this is not the same.  I don't want special sorting.

Comment: Your query appears to be syntactically correct, and yes, LogParser supports arbitrary ASC and DESC for each field in the ORDER BY clause. You can verify it by running directly from the command line. If it works from the command line, then I'd say it's a problem with LogParser Studio.

Comment: Wait... @GabrieleGiuseppini, you wrote the original (says Wikipedia)?  :-O  Sorry to say, but the help file contradicts you...

Comment: Ouch, I'm using a version that has never seen the light, I should probably downgrade before I answer questions again...:-) Sorry about that, @Goozak.

Comment: Ah!  Could that be the mythical LP3 I've seen mentioned on the Web around 2006?  So...  It does exists!  

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the help file has the answer :

> Tip: Differently than the standard SQL language, the Log Parser SQL-Like language supports **only one** DESC or ASC keyword for the whole ORDER BY clause.

So, RTFM  :-)